# command alias with appended commands

Tags: bash, latex, alias, pdflatex

I'm trying to write a bash alias which would take a command:

```
$ ptex example.tex
```

and run:

```
$ pdflatex example.tex && rm !(*.tex|*.pdf|*.bib)
```

The thing I don't understand how to do is to get the argument in the right place and then append the remove command.

Or if there is an option for pdflatex which would not generate the additional files, that would be even better, but I've looked and never found one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Can't do that with an alias, they're not that flexible. Functions however, are perfectly suited:

```
ptex() {
    pdflatex "$1" && rm !(*.tex|*.pdf|*.bib)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wondered if aliases could do it.  I've never used a function before.